# tWhy does error insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost keep popping up gas * price * value not enough ? I know I have the funds

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

```
USDT = new ethers.Contract(
USDTADDRESS,
ABI,
    mywallet // wallet is fine, can call send transaction  normally to other signers and total supply from erc20, balance returns 10000 ETH, 
);
let tc = await tokenB.totalSupply();
let value = await mywallet.getBalance();
console.log(`USDT supply:${tc.toString()} ETH balance: ${ethers.utils.formatEther(value)}`);
const tsc = await USDT.transfer(mywallet.address, 0);
```

I know this question has been rehashed many times however most errors seem to be with either a faulty framework or insufficient funds, none of which seem to be the case here. This is a rinkeby hardhat testnet fork

Comment: What's the contract address? Do you have a failed transaction hash? Some libraries display that generic error message when the transaction fails. For the real error you have to check the transaction receipt and/or trace the transaction.

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x7b1ed0bff6ae2bab29603f67664a60fec0c2c5eeaceb409b76cdee90b009574e. Doing some research, the issue seems to be with the sender value however, as you can see, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you search the contract source for the error message reported in the [transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x7b1ed0bff6ae2bab29603f67664a60fec0c2c5eeaceb409b76cdee90b009574e)

> ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance

It is in the `_transfer` function

```
function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

    _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
}
```

The sender is trying to send more than the available balance.

Looking at the [sender ERC20 history](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0d0f74061105d40a447fdf98cbf068a4b4762218#tokentxns) they never received the tokens they are trying to send (`0x3b00ef435fa4fcff5c209a37d1f3dcff37c705ad`).

Comment: Wait, but didn't the open zeppelin docs mention that there were only 2 arguments?https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20, reciever and amount? So I would assume that the token address must be the first argument then?

Comment: @alex234 I'm quoting is the internal function ` _transfer` (with an underscore), it is not the public one. The names are quite clear: sender (the account that owns the tokens), recipient (the account that will receive the tokens), amount (the token amount).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. But if I'm understanding this correctly now, how do I get tokens from an established contract if I have none to start with?

Comment: @alex234 I got the error from the transaction link in the comment: *Fail with error 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance'*. Then searched the contract code on etherscan for that string and found in the internal `_transfer` function. It shows where the error comes from: the sender is trying to transfer funds that it doesn't have so it will never work. This contract has a `mint` function that seems to allow minting yourself some tokens. In any case it is a test network so you can deploy your own copy of the contract if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I already minted some new tokens for myself and thank you for taking time out of your day to assist me.